# get the name of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

The code

```
a={'k1':['a',2,3]}
b={'k2':[2,'b',4]}
for i in [a,b]:
   print(i)
```

prints out the value of `a` and `b`. But what I actually wanted it to print the dictionary names, i.e.

```
a
b
```

My current solution is this:

```
a={'k1':['a',2,3]}
b={'k2':[2,'b',4]}
for i in [a,b]:
    if i is a:
        print('a')
    elif i is b:
        print('b')
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: If you want to treat them differently, why even add them in an array and loop it? Sounds like poor design.

Comment: What are you really trying to do here? Why do you need the *variable name*? This kind of question pops up regularly and there's usually no good reason for wanting this, the problem can always be solved in a much better way.

Comment: @deceze In fact, the dictionary  is used to groupby in pandas. the name is used to subset the data like :data[data.col1==name]

Comment: Perhaps you'd rather like to make `a` and `b` itself keys in an object…? `o = dict(a={'k1': ...}, b={...}); for k, v in o.items(): ...`

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get the name of a value. There's also never a need to.

Names refer to values. Many names can refer to the same value. Thus, there cannot be a "true name" for any given object as all names are equal.

Consider

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = x
>>> x is y
True
```

Now, what's *the* name of the value 5? It does not make sense.

Consider

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = x[:] # shallow copy of x
>>> x is y
False
```

Now, what's *the* name of the list [1,2,3], which exists twice? It does not make sense.

If you are desperate to give your dictionaries a persistent name, add it as a key-value pair, e.g.

```
>>> mydic = {1:2, 'name':'Bob'}
>>> mydic['name']
'Bob'
```

But consider carefully why you actually want to do this. Chances are that you don't even want to.